# Regular to match a string with atleast one letter and all characters should be in lower case

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Regular expression. I am looking efficient way to write regular expression to match a string with at least one letter and all characters  should be in lower case

```
Ex-
 test->true
 tesT->false
 test123->true
 test@#$->true
 ABC->false
 teST123->false
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `([a-z]+)`  `a-z` allows only small letters `+` for atleat 1 character

Comment: Even though I told I am new to RegEx, I dont know why people are down voting

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvotes either actually.  The question is clear and has a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
^[^A-Z]*[a-z]+[^A-Z]*$
```

A string that matches this *must* contain at least one lowercase letter and cannot have uppercase letters.

The ^ and $ obliges the regular expression to match the whole string (not just a part).  The [^A-Z]* means an empty string or a string not containing upper case letters.  This is combined on both sides to the [a-z]+ which is a string containing one or more lowercase letters.

Comment: @JavaP Updated.  Does this explain it?

Comment: Got it. Thanks Neil

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

`^(?=[^A-Z]+$)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]).*$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QbrJGH/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?=[^A-Z]+$)` - [Positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to validate that there is no capital letter present in the test string until the end of the string
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - Positive lookahead to validate that there is atleast one smallcase letter `a-z`
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except the newline character. This works in conjunction with the above-mentioned 2 conditions.
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you ask for

```
[a-z]+
```

Comment: This won't match test@#$.

Comment: Read over the fact you wanted characters aswell, look at the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

import re
list1 = ['test','tesT','test123','test@#$','ABC','teST123']
for word in list1:
    matchtext = re.match("(^[^A-Z]+$)",word)
    print(matchtext)

output:
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='test'>
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='test123'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='test@#$'>
None
None
```